# How can I stop cron after five iteration

Tags: node.js

How can I stop cron when value of `i` is grater than 5?

```
var i=0
new testCron('1 * * * * *', function()
{
  try 
{
  http.get(url,function(err,response)
  {
          if(err && i<5)
          {
            temp[i]=err;
            console.log("its err no",i);
            i++;
          }
          else
          {
            console.log("its reach in else");
          }
        }
      )
      throw err;
    }
    catch(e){

    }
  }, null, true, 'Asia/Kolkata');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 0
new testCron('1 * * * * *', function () {
    if(i == 5) 
        process.exit(); // <---- program will terminate
    try {
        http.get(url, function (err, response) {
            if (err && i < 5) {
                temp[i] = err;
                console.log("its err no", i);
                i++;
            } else {
                console.log("its reach in else");
            }
        })
        throw err;
    } catch (e) {

    }
}, null, true, 'Asia/Kolkata');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `exit()` (alias of `die()`) function.

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_exit.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_die.asp